# how can the language for rdp sessions in remmina be set? mine changed to slovenian

Tags: language, remmina

My English remmina-rdp connection one day switched to slovenian (i think it switched when it was trying to reconnect to an rdp session more times than the maximum set in the preferences). where can this language setting be changed/set? i could not find anything in `~/.remmina`.

```
system: linux mint 18.3 MATE edition
remmina version: 1.4.3
```

Comment: which interface exactly have switched the langage? is it remmina itself? is it the remote machine? what system are you using on the remote machine? are talking about the gui language or the keyboard layout? is the rest of your main system in english?

Comment: They are mentioning the same issue as [here](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/2163). Already detailed how to fix it in my post. @intika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a translation issue (with EN_GB) and will be sorted out with the next version of Remmina.

Answer (score 1):

After searching for a bit, i noticed that the same exact problem you're having was already [reported](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/2163) (quite recently too) on the official gitlab repo of remmina. Go [here](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/2163#what-is-the-expected-correct-behavior) if you want to see what i mean.

Now for the possible cause:

- As written on the post i linked above, the error/problem you're facing might stem from a newer version of FreeRDP, not Remmina (as stated by [him](https://gitlab.com/antenore) on the aforementioned post)
- It comes from an older version of remmina that wasn't removed entirely after an upgrade.(as also stated on the very last comment on the aforementioned link)

Possible solution:

Since you're on Linux Mint, i suggest doing as the last comment on the post recommended, and completely purge both remmina and FreeRDP and then install it.

```bsh
sudo apt purge -y "?name(^remmina.*)" "?name(^libfreerdp.*)" "?name(^freerdp.*)" "?name(^libwinpr.*)" && sudo apt install -y "?name(^remmina.*)" "?name(^libfreerdp.*)" "?name(^freerdp.*)" "?name(^libwinpr.*)"
```

Comment: kinda curious why there a downvote, especially since the answer fix it...

Comment: re-installing did not fix the issue but discussing the issue using the provided link helped. thanks alot!